# Is there any function in R that can find : average sales contribution of total sales?

Tags: r

Assume a company that we have info about Total sales and the amount of sales in three counties CA , TX and WI.
How can i calculate : the average sales contribution of the three states of total company sales

I need furthermore to find : the same average percentages for each year, month of the year and day of the week.

EDITED !!!

```
structure(list(CA = c(11047, 9925, 11322, 12251, 16610, 14696
), TX = c(7381, 5912, 9006, 6226, 9440, 9376), WI = c(6984, 3309, 
8883, 9533, 11882, 8664), Total = c(25412, 19146, 29211, 28010, 
37932, 32736), date = structure(c(1296518400, 1296604800, 1296691200, 
1296777600, 1296864000, 1296950400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), event_type = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Sporting"
), snap_CA = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), snap_TX = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1), snap_WI = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: @r2evans how can i upload an excel sheet with data ???

Comment: The dput function can upload a data.frame as text

Comment: type `dput(head(WalData))` in your console and copy/paste the output. When you paste the output on here, highlight it and press `CTRL + K` to format it as code.

Comment: I follow the steps of you colleague thanks @Bruno

Comment: do you want the average off all percentual contributions (possibly do not add exactly 100%) or wou.d the total contribution per time frame (year/month/etc.) be sufficent to be considered average

Comment: Mr/Ms @DPH :  I want to calculate the average sales share of the three states on the company's total sales. Also, calculate the same average percentages for each year, month of the year and day of the week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood your problem correctly a possible solution would be this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(YEAR = lubridate::year(date),
                MONTH = lubridate::month(date),
                WEEKDAY = lubridate::wday(date),
                P_CA = CA / Total,
                P_TX = TX / Total,
                P_WI = WI / Total) 

# Average per Year
df1 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(YEAR) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(AV_CA = mean(P_CA, na.rm = TRUE),
                   AV_TX = mean(P_TX, na.rm = TRUE),
                   AV_WI = mean(P_WI, na.rm = TRUE))

   YEAR AV_CA AV_TX AV_WI
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2011 0.444 0.278 0.278

# Average per Month
df1 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(MONTH) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(AV_CA = mean(P_CA, na.rm = TRUE),
                   AV_TX = mean(P_TX, na.rm = TRUE),
                   AV_WI = mean(P_WI, na.rm = TRUE))

  MONTH AV_CA AV_TX AV_WI
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2 0.444 0.278 0.278

# Average per Weekday
df1 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(WEEKDAY) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(AV_CA = mean(P_CA, na.rm = TRUE),
                   AV_TX = mean(P_TX, na.rm = TRUE),
                   AV_WI = mean(P_WI, na.rm = TRUE))

  WEEKDAY AV_CA AV_TX AV_WI
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1 0.449 0.286 0.265
2       3 0.435 0.290 0.275
3       4 0.518 0.309 0.173
4       5 0.388 0.308 0.304
5       6 0.437 0.222 0.340
6       7 0.438 0.249 0.313
```

For this dummy data all will up to 100% but when using a larger dataset this might not be true

Comment: i will try it as soon as possible , maybe in a half an hour !!!  It seems that is what i want !!! @DPH

Comment: It comes with the following error and i cant figure out whats wrong ???  The error messages continues with the run of the code .  Any thoughts ??? @DPH
> df1 <- df %>% 
+   dplyr::mutate(YEAR = lubridate::year(date),
+                 MONTH = lubridate::month(date),
+                 WEEKDAY = lubridate::wday(date),
+                 P_CA = CA / Total,
+                 P_TX = TX / Total,
+                 P_WI = WI / Total) 
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @ilaiaszarkHD; I just tried the code on your structure as df again on a new R skript and it works. Please verify that you have the latest dplyr and lubridate packages installed. Also make sure that your "date" colum is actually in date format and possibly you have a "date" variable declared outside of the dataframe (maybe use a different name for it or just clean the enviornemnt and run the code again). The "+" signs must be remove from the code but I guess you just copied that from the console...

Comment: I made a fool mistake, i forgot to define the df as my data (df<- WalData) , it works fine now ! Thanks a lot @DPH .